# Docker file for spacy and scispacy model deployment in AWS sagemaker

Tags: dockerfile, spacy, amazon-sagemaker

Can somebody share the sample docker file for spacy, scispacy libraries and there corresponding models in AWS Sagemaker under category of bringing your own pre trained models

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. check this -https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Did you solve this? i have same issue.